# Open button in new tab/window

Tags: button, browser

Is it possible from a users point of view, to click a button and the result to load in a new tab/window, **not automatically**.

**Like if you middle click on a link in some browsers or right click -> Open in new tab/window.**
Can you do this with a button? Or would you need a browser plugin?

Is this at all possible? I know you can make custom buttons and such but this is more out of curiosity.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq]

Comment: It is programming related, just not directly. Depending on what I find out here will be programming based. :P

Comment: If you meant a `<button>` or `<input type='button'>` then a simple test will demonstrate that your browser does not offer "Open in New Tab" on those elements.  However, a normal `<a>` link could be styled to look like a button, and have that functionality.

Comment: If you *really really* wanted to make this functionality available on a `<button>`, you could override the context menu with your own context menu, which could offer the 'Open in a New Tab/Window' option.  But that would be a crazy thing to do, if you could just change the `<button>` to an `<a>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

When setting up the form, you just need to change the target:

```
<form action="form_action.asp" method="get" target="_blank"></form>
```

Comment: NOT automatically. Is it possible through the browser.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this? You want to be able to choose if its a window OR a tab?

Comment: No I simply mean is there any way of middle/right clicking a button to open in new tab/window.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, now -- How is this programming-related?

Comment: Well then I question, have you tried it yourself? It always depends on the browser and if they have that functionality, but if you're asking from the users point of view, this is something you can test out.

Comment: Mainly because I don't know all browsers functionality as well as extensions/addons and such.

Answer (score -1):

---

You can just use HTML:

```
<a target="_blank" href="YourAmazingURL">Click here for Amazing URL</a>
```

Another Example:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```

This takes advantage of the target attribute.

More information on the target attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp
Also: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

## XHTML:

For XHTML, just do this:

```
<a href="YourAmazingURL" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;">Click here for Amazing URL</a>
```

Or, again:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;">Google</a>
```

---

Comment: If I'm correct, hes asking about when you submit a form, but same deal anyway :)

Comment: Yeah, well it's pretty much the same idea.

Comment: No I simply mean is there any way of middle/right clicking a button to open in new tab/window

Comment: This did not answer the question. OP asks if there is a way specifically using `<button>` element tags, not using `<a>` elements.